# Causing images to appear/disappear on button click

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am attempting to use actionscript 2.0 in order to hide an image and cause another image to become visible based on a button click, I can't seem to get anything to work though I just get errors and nothing happens

```
orangeButton.onRelease = function(){
if(orange._visible == false){
    orange._visible = true;
    dots._visible = false;
    }
else
    orange.visible = false;
}
```

I get an error stating that I need an identifier after line 4

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
orangeButton.onRelease = function(){
if(orange._visible == false){
    orange._visible = true;
    dots._visible = false;
}
else {     // added a curly-brace here
    orange.visible = false;
}
```